# How to run a module pass in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to find a way to optimize away empty global constructors. Previous optimizations will turn constructors into functions that do nothing. I need to add a new pass to remove these functions from `llvm.global_ctors`.

First, I tried `optimizeGlobalCtorsList` but this function doesn't actually call the callback I give it even though `llvm.global_ctors` is populated.

Then I tried running `GlobalOptPass`. I tried this:

```
llvm::GlobalOptPass pass;
llvm::ModuleAnalysisManager MAM{true};
pass.run(module, MAM);
```

This ends up dereferencing a null pointer in `AnalysisManager::lookupPass`. I think I need to perform some sort of initialization or registration but I don't know how to do that. All the references on "llvm pass registration" talk about registering the pass with `opt`. I don't want to do that. I just want to run the pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in `lib/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.cpp` (or `lib/Passes/PassBuilder.cpp` for the new pass manager) to see how `opt` sets up its pass pipeline.  The code for `opt` is in `tools/opt/opt.cpp` and is very small, delegating almost all of its work to the core libraries.

You could use `opt` as a template for your own tool, or you could hack on the pass building pipline to insert your pass where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

The new pass manager can be used directly with a standalone pass using the solution i described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447985/how-to-automatically-register-and-load-modern-pass-in-clang/75999804#75999804)