# Clang run concrete LLVM pass with new Pass Manager registry

Tags: clang, llvm

I have have dynamic library - collection of LLVM passes. I want to omit calling `opt` call and use clang. Having looked into [How to automatically register and load modern Pass in Clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447985/how-to-automatically-register-and-load-modern-pass-in-clang) , i found flag of loading plugin, but it was not clear how list of passes is provided: tried passing `-passes=` flag to LLVM interface with the following command

```
clang -O0 -fpass-plugin=mylib.dylib -mllvm -passes=mypass sourcefile.cpp
```

but it returns `Unknown command line argument '-passes=mypass'`.

Running `clang --help-hidden` has shown supposedly familiar flag `-foptimization-record-passes=<regex>` , but it didn't perform pass too.  Checking list of `clang -mllvm --help` shown another peculiar option. But there was no `-passes` option in the list.

```
--print-pipeline-passes Print a '-passes' compatible string describing the pipeline (best-effort only)
```

I want to know, whether it is possible for concrete passes to be run by compiler and the means of doing so.

Comment: see the example I wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447985/how-to-automatically-register-and-load-modern-pass-in-clang/75999804#75999804

Answer (score 0):

As of Aug 2022 [they say](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56137#issuecomment-1200957606) the way is to add `-Xclang -load -Xclang mylib.dylib`.